# Can't get handle on button attribute. Can't find it from page source

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm having some problems getting a handle on a button, and in particular, a specific button attribute.  Essentially, I have two buttons on my page.  The button I need to verify has has an attribute of "disabled".  The problem I have is that I can't seem to get a handle on it - it's almost as if it's not there but it's clearly within the source of my web page.  Here is the code for both buttons below

```
<button type="button" class="btn-number" data-type="yes" data-field="quant" disabled="disabled"><i class="fht-yes"></i></button>
<a href="#"> Choose flight </a>
<button type="button" class="btn-number" data-type="no" data-field="quant"><i class="fht-no"></i></button>
</div></div>    
</div>
```

Here are some things I have tried:

```
IWebElement ButtonDisabled = Setup.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='box']/div/div[1]/div/button[1]"));
String VerifyButtonDisabled = ButtonDisabled.GetAttribute("outerHTML");

if (VerifyButtonDisabled.Contains("disabled"))
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("pass");
}
else
{
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("fail");
}
```

When I run this, I get the following debug trace back:

Debug Trace:

```
<button type="button" class="btn-number" data-type="yes" data-field="quant"><i class="fht-yes""></i></button>
```

Notice that the "disabled" attribute isn't being returned?

I have tried also to execute JS directly

```
IWebElement ButtonDisabled = Setup.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='box']/div/div[1]/div/button[1]"));

IJavaScriptExecutor js = Setup.driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
String GetElement = (String)js.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].outerHTML", ButtonDisabled);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(GetElement);
```

Again, I get the same debug trace sent back:

Debug Trace:

```
<button type="button" class="btn-number" data-type="yes" data-field="quant"><i class="fht-yes""></i></button>
```

I also tried to get the entire page's outer HTML like so:

```
String BodyText = Setup.driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).GetAttribute("outerHTML");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(BodyText);
```

One other note worth pointing out is that the button is always enabled.  When I use the 'locals' debug tools on the button it always has an "enabled" property so I can't use the .getAttribute("disabled") method to verify it either.

Does anyone have any ideas?  :)  Many thanks for some help with this

Comment: `runat="server"` are you familiar with that

Comment: Not at all but going to read into it - thanks

Comment: Your XPath is heavily dependant on positions, it's probably picking the wrong one. Give the element an ID or find it in a "better" way.

Answer (score 0):

You could just modify the XPath expression to select by *disabled* attribute

```
this.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='box']/div/div[1]/div/button[@disabled='disabled']"));
```

Should get you the button with *disabled* attribute set.

```
this.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='box']/div/div[1]/div/button[not(@disabled='disabled')]"));
```

Should get you the button containing no *disabled* attribute.

Assuming of course the rest of the original XPath expression is correct...